# Docker: Can't login from console

Tags: docker, authentication

I'm newbie in docker and I'm trying to login to docker from my console but I've got an error. If I try to login to docker from a browser everything works fine.

[image]

The error that I've got is:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To verify, the browser page you login to is hub.docker.com? Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Yes, I login into hub.docker.com and I'm no behind a proxy. I have updated my original post with an screencap from my browser

Comment: As you can see your Username or Password is wrong. Check it on the mainpage

Comment: I know it, but I put muy username correctly and my password too. If I try to login with docker login -u=josecarlosbcn -p=password I've got the same error!!!